# What fonts may considered as default for web

Tags: html, fonts, cross-browser, cross-platform

Well, basically, the subject says for it self: what fonts I may take as default for cross-browser/platform, client-side web development?

Answer (score 0):

This link should provide a bit more information on what you're after: [CSS Web Safe Fonts](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp)

**EDIT**

It is recommended by the [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#generic-font-families) to have a fallback mechanism for specifying a font family after a font declaration, in order to ensure these are rendered in CSS by the device. These include:

- serif
- sans-serif
- cursive
- fantasy
- monospace

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: It isn't a good link anyway. It describes it's content as "commonly used font combinations", which is not the same as *well supported*. It doesn't have any date on it (my gut feeling is that it is about a decade out of date). It doesn't describe which platforms come with those fonts.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this Quentin. On reflection, you may of course be right that the webpage is out of date, yet no official clarification is made on that page confirming this. Therefore, a 'gut' feeling does not constitute that the answer is irrelevant, especially due to the fact that the user asked for 'cross-browser/platform' default fonts, which this page does in fact explain this in relevant detail.

Comment: No, it doesn't. As I said in my previous comment, it claims to list "commonly used font combinations" not "fonts commonly installed on people's systems".

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out, however, I need a reliable piece of information. I also googled the subject and couldn't find anything reliable and up to date(or something close enough to our days). That's why I'm asking here for some help with this.

Comment: Well, I thought the use of the words 'Web Safe Fonts' in the page title would be at least partly sufficient enough to provide some direction to the user into their question.